# React - CSS Styles messed up after building React App

Tags: css, reactjs, pdf

I've seen a lot of problems alike mine, with multiple solutions as well, but none of them worked for me.

I made a React app using `npx create-react-app prima-prova`, as shown in the official tutorial.

When developing, "npm start" works perfectly, but when running "npm run build && serve -s build/"  the styles (only CSS) will get all messed up.

In the Dev Environment

[image: In the Dev Environment]

In production

[image: In production]

From what i've seen this issue is common when using the Material UI library, but since I don't use it, it shouldn't matter.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mikecousins/react-pdf": "^5.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.5.0",
    "animated-scroll-to": "^2.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "pdf-viewer-reactjs": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-fileupload-progress": "^0.5.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.0.1",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

These are my dependencies.

If i had to take a wild guess I'd say that it was the `pdf-viewer-reactjs": "^2.0.2` library to mess everything up, but it's the best one I've found to display PDFs in my WebPage. Is there a better way to do such a thing or was it something else to break everything ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It might be silly but did you try removing your dependencies one by one and see which would be responsible?

Also, I would make sure to check which classnames get messed up and figure out why these specific classes. Because it looks like you get partial styling anyway.